# ctrl+p not working on visual studio code's WSL extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2, visual-studio-code-server

The symptom was that ctrl+p and "Find in files" only returned results from opened editors.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found the issue that describes my problem.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/709

I called `~/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node_modules/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg` from shell and got a `Segmentation Fault` which was an indicator to me that the vscode-server installation is messed up.

I renamed the `~/.vscode-server` to `~/.vscode-server-backup` to trigger a reinstall and the ctrl+p started working.

Because the new `~/.vscode-server` lacked some stuff, I copied the `rg` into `~/.vscode-server-backup` and moved it back to `~/.vscode-server`

I tried to describe my solution in the Github issue, but it's locked. So I decided to post the solution here for others.